# Problem selecting an inserted element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select the element which I inserted with `after()`, but I can't select it.

In the Firebug console I can use `$('.new-tree-node-close')` to get `<span.new-tree-node-close>`, but in my page I can't get it.

```html
<ul> 
  <li class="tree-l2"><a class="reference internal" href="#">One</a></li> 
  <li class="tree-l2"><a class="reference internal" href="#">Two</a></li> 
  <li class="tree-l2"><a class="reference internal" href="#">There</a></li>
  <li class="tree-l2-new">
      <div class="new-tree-node-l2">New</div>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //When User click 'New',remove it and insert new input box and 'Close'
    $('.new-tree-node-l2').click(function(event) {
        $(this).parent(':last').after('<input name="" class="new-tree-node-title"><span class="new-tree-node-close">[Close]</span>');
        $(this).remove();    
    });

    //When user click the 'Close',do something..
    $('.new-tree-node-close').click(function(event) {
        alert("Do Something...");
    });
});
```

[Here is the main code and more detail in the jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/p73MP/)

Comment: you need to use jquery live function to bind functions for dynamically added elements. $('.new-tree-node-close').live('click', unction(event){}

Comment: Thank you @Jayantha,I never pay attention to this function until today.Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the code to

```
//When user click the 'Close',do something..
$('.new-tree-node-close').live('click', function(event) {
    alert("Do Something...");
});
```

using [live](http://api.jquery.com/live) instead of click.